# Which keystore to use?

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore

I have an android app which is available on google play.

While creating an apk for release, there was a keystore that was created for signing.

My question is, if after the release, I have some enhancements underway (like facebook or google+ integration), which requires that the dev registers his app using the keystore, which keystore do I use?

Should it be the debug keystore (~/.android/debug.keystore) or the one that was created while packaging my app?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers so far.

To confirm, from the below answers I understand that, when testing this enhancement (before deploying the app to play store) & to register my app at facebook, I will be using the keystore that was used for signing the first apk file for this app and NOT the 'debug.keystore'. Correct?

But, while testing, wouldn't my app be sending 'debug.keystore', if I am building on eclipse platform? Or does the 'debug.keystore' become invalid once I have a new keystore generated for creating the previous apk file?

It's rather too confusing, and want to be clear with this...

Comment: A developer can continue to use a debug keystore for short-term *testing* of a development version of an already published app, but it won't be able to share locally stored data with the release-signed version (in fact you will have to accept the removal of that data before you can switch the version used on a device).  And of course the play store won't accept a version signed with a debug key, so as you prepare your release candidate at some point you will have to switch to the release key.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use, keystore which is used for generating apk file for playstore. Dont use another keystore, becoz it will give new one but wont updated the old one.

Answer (score 1):

**debug keystore (~/.android/debug.keystore)** is not going to work for you.

As you mention that your application is already available in Google Play, that means while singing your application it ask Create new Keystore or use Existing one

[image]

Then choose **Use existing keystore**

Give your **existing keystore path, and password.**

This will give you a build that you can release in Google Play..

Before that make sure that increase the **android:versionCode** and **android:versionName**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YOUR_PACKAGE"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Hope this help you.
Plz ask if having any sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your signing keystore which you used while uploading your app to developer console.  **The one that was created while packaging your app**

Answer (score 0):

only used for your signing keystore because already you release the application in play store so you can use new key that time is not release for updated version it's a one of the new application so you can use previous kestore for your updated appp.